# ¿Por qué no me reconoce la fecha en el constructor?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Alumno {
    private String nombAlumno;
    private Date fechaNac;

    public Alumno(String nombAlumno, Date fechaNac) {
        this.nombAlumno = nombAlumno;
        this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AlumnoDAO {
  public static List<Alumno> lista() {
    List<Alumno> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Alumno c1 = new Alumno("juan",22/12/2000);
    list.add(c1);
    return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores, primero, un *error de "sintaxis"*, debes pasar la fecha como un String (entre comillas), y el segundo crear el propio objeto *Date*, que es lo que espera recibir el constructor de tu clase *Alumno*, es decir que tu línea:

```
Alumno c1 = new Alumno("juan",22/12/2000);
```

debería de ser:

```
Alumno c1 = new Alumno("juan", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("22/12/2000"));
```

o bien:

```
Date miDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("22/12/2000");
Alumno c1 = new Alumno("juan", miDate);
```

incluyendo además las clases que correspondan al principio del fichero:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;
```

*Ejemplos de conversión de un String en un objeto de tipo Date:
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date*